Is the coupon usage limitation broken in general due to async update?
We have coupons which should be usable only once.
In my integration tests I was able to use them twice.
I found out, that this is linked to the queue runners. When I start the queue consumers locally, my tests pass.
The process boils down to the sales.rule.update.coupon.usage TOPIC which is used in \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Service\CouponUsagePublisher and queues the update of the coupon usages. As soon this job ran, the coupon can not be used a second time.
Now this got me thinking: I believe there is no guarantee, how fast a queue job is executed. It's asynchronous and it should not matter if it is delayed.
But the above case shows very clear, that if there is problem with the queue (for example the job was ended and waits for a new invocation by the cron) or if the queue runner is just busy with other jobs, there is seems to be a time frame which should not be neglected where a second order which the same single-use coupon code can be done. This is very problematic, if the merchant is giving out codes with a value of > 1000 € to be used once.

Am I assuming correctly, that the coupon usage tracking here is problematic?
Can this be switched to a synchronous processing by configuration or a plugin so that such a a coupon can never be used twice?

EDIT:
Seems indeed a bug:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38017

In this case, the consumer is correctly set up, so the coupon code usage is raised correctly. However, due to the queue mechanism, this is not done fast enough, so a customer can place multiple orders with the same coupon code within the time period the system needs to raise the coupon usage.
This can be exploited by customers, e.g. if coupon codes are used as simple gift cards.
Maybe it isn't a good idea to use queues in this scenario where it relies on an immediate raise of the coupon code usage? Or a coupon code should already be blocked when it is applied to the quote.

Question is how this can be fixed easily?

I have posted a potential workaround for this in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38017#issuecomment-2141574825
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Coupon/Quote$ diff -u UpdateCouponUsages.php.orig UpdateCouponUsages.php
--- UpdateCouponUsages.php.orig 2024-05-31 11:05:21.475190656 +0200
+++ UpdateCouponUsages.php      2024-05-31 11:12:30.899470917 +0200
@@ -8,6 +8,7 @@
 namespace Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Quote;
 
 use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
+use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\Processor as CouponUsageProcessor;
 use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\UpdateInfo;
 use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\UpdateInfoFactory;
 use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Service\CouponUsagePublisher;
@@ -33,10 +34,12 @@
      */
     public function __construct(
         CouponUsagePublisher $couponUsagePublisher,
-        UpdateInfoFactory $updateInfoFactory
+        UpdateInfoFactory $updateInfoFactory,
+        CouponUsageProcessor $couponUsageProcessor
     ) {
         $this->couponUsagePublisher = $couponUsagePublisher;
         $this->updateInfoFactory = $updateInfoFactory;
+        $this->couponUsageProcessor = $couponUsageProcessor;
     }
 
     /**
@@ -59,6 +62,7 @@
         $updateInfo->setCustomerId((int)$quote->getCustomerId());
         $updateInfo->setIsIncrement($increment);
 
-        $this->couponUsagePublisher->publish($updateInfo);
+        //$this->couponUsagePublisher->publish($updateInfo);
+        $this->couponUsageProcessor->process($updateInfo);
     }
 }

